# Using Model to define a group/range of numbers then populate a new field with the new definition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, rank

In one single table I have a rank in one field, and let's say I have rank 1 through 3 in one field and I want to define that group of rankings of 1,2 and 3 as having a score of '10', then ranks 4 through 7 as having a score of'9' and so on, how would I do that in ModelBuilder?

In other words I am trying to define groups of ranks. So far I am trying to look at using python script in a calculate field variable in ModelBuilder.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to visualise what you're asking - could you provide some screenshots or examples?

Comment: Have you checked the ArcGIS Help Documents?  The calculate field example at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0 seems to be exactly what you are asking for. If it is not what you are needing, you need to be more specific about the help you need.

Comment: I think CStarbard my have answered the question, but let me try to clarify. I have records in one field that are ranked from one to 14. If the records falls in to the 1 to 3 ranking, I want to give that 1 to 3 group a score of 5 (5 being the highest score that can be received). For the next group of rankings, 4 to 7, I want to assign that next group a score of 4. Is that making sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to assign arbitrary values to your scores, I'd use a python dictionary in your calculate field portion of your model. Here's an example code block...

```
def find_val(x):
    return {1 : 10, 2 : 10, 3 : 10, 4 : 9, 5 : 9, 6 : 9, 7 : 9 }[x]
```

On the left of the colon is your ranking value, and on the right is your score for that ranking.

If your rankings are based on ranges of scores, then a simple if statement would do the trick...

```
def find_val(x):
    if (x > 0 and x <= 3):
        return 10
    elif (x > 3 and x <= 7):
        return 9
```

Comment: Thanks Cstarbird. I am going to give both of these scripts a try to see which works better.

Comment: Also, in your script where you have "x"...should I substitute the actual field name there, or should say something like 'Field 2' where the 'x' is?

Comment: No, you need to call this function in your output...

`find_val(!Field_Name!)`

but replace Field_name with the name of your field.